# possibility to create a group for user php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

What's the best way for add possibility for users can create a group?

My problem is for SQL table, i don't know how i can do it easily.

*i have created a simple diagram :*

[image]

But I think, I need something because if a user want to join or create a specific group how I can do that?

Comment: Please be more specific. Do you need an `insert` query?

Comment: @juergend i don't need insert, just logic of create group. i editing for detail.

Comment: if a user needs belong to 2 groups ? check http://www.askjohnobiee.com/2013/08/how-to-bridge-tables-and-many-to-many.html

Comment: you need a table called users_in_group to join the groups with the users, so the user can be a member of more than one group.

Comment: @Placeholders_in_use yes,it's exactly what i have forgotten thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need many-to-many relationship. Create a new table, e.g. "user_groups" with:
- id of user
- id of group

Comment: Okay, so i need many-to-many relationship, I will look for documentation. Thank you!